# Another java program rebus

Tags: rebus, movies

```
public class Program {
    static boolean can;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        can = true;
        if (can) {
            try {
                doSomething();
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        } else {
            doSomething();
        }
    }
    static void doSomething() throws Exception {}
}
```

What movie title is this referencing?

Comment: Oops, I answered without realizing this was a movie *title*

Comment: I almost went with another  (incorrect answer) but that could for a nice rebus in this style aswell... I may post it later, if I can figure out suitable syntax without making it a dead giveaway.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Could it be

> *Catch Me If You Can*?

Comment: Exception variable should be renamed, imo. :)

Answer (score 1):

> If at first you don't succeed, try, try again.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to edit this answer to explain how you reached this conclusion given the information in the question?

Comment: *FirstTimeGuesser, this is not a movie title, please try again :-)